# Unable to create subscription filter to KinesisStream using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I  want to stream some logs from cloudwatch to S3. For this I have created the resources via CDK.
The code relevant to Kinesis is -

```js
const rootStream = new Stream(this, 'Root', {
      streamName: `stream-name`
    });

    const firehoseRole = new Role(this, `some-id`, {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('firehose.amazonaws.com'),
      roleName: `some-role-name`
    });

  rootStream.grantRead(firehoseRole);
  rootStream.grant(firehoseRole, 'kinesis:DescribeStream');

const firehoseStreamToS3 = new CfnDeliveryStream(...);// omitted the large config  

    const subFilterDestination = new KinesisDestination(rootStream);

    const subFilter = new SubscriptionFilter(this, 'xyz', {
      destination: subFilterDestination,
      filterPattern: FilterPattern.literal('some=pattern'),
      logGroup: myLogGroup
    });
    subFilter.node.addDependency(myLogGroup);
```

During deployment I get the error

```
X:XX:XX PM | CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::Logs::SubscriptionFilter        | LogProcessingFilterXYZABC
Resource handler returned message: "Could not deliver test message to specified Kinesis stream. Check if the given kinesis strea
m is in ACTIVE state. (Service: CloudWatchLogs, Status Code: 400, Request ID: abcdef-bbbb-cccc-dddd-xxxxxxxxx)" (RequestTok
en: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InternalFailure)
```

The IAM role I have created for the kinesis stream has the following policies. When I try to create a subscription filter from AWS console I get the same error 'Could not deliver test message to specified Kinesis stream. Check if the given kinesis stream is in ACTIVE state.'

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "kinesis:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:xxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:lambda:lambda-to-be-invoked-by-stream",
                "arn:aws:lambda:lambda-to-be-invoked-by-stream:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "glue:BatchGetPartition",
                "glue:GetPartition",
                "glue:GetPartitions",
                "glue:GetTable",
                "glue:GetTables",
                "glue:GetTableVersion",
                "glue:GetTableVersions",
                "glue:BatchCreatePartition",
                "glue:BatchDeletePartition",
                "glue:CreatePartition",
                "glue:DeletePartition",
                "glue:UpdatePartition"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:glue:xxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:PutObject*",
                "s3:Abort*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-where-streamed-data-is-saved",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-where-streamed-data-is-saved/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "logs:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:source-log-group-from-where-I-want-to-stream:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the cause of this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing IAM permissions, which you must handle yourself if you use [L1 Constructs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) like `CfnDeliveryStream`.

Consider the L2 Firehose [S3Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-kinesisfirehose-destinations-alpha.S3Bucket.html) construct, *"An S3 bucket destination for data from a Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream."*  It's an experimental API in the `@aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose-destinations-alpha` package.

The alpha construct can be useful even if you want to avoid experimental APIs - take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose-destinations/lib/s3-bucket.ts) for hints about how to properly wire up your `CfnDeliveryStream`.

Comment: I have added the IAM permissions of the kinesis stream role in my question. I added all that seemed to be the issue but no success.

Comment: @Akshay Did you try the L2 construct?

Comment: thanks,  didn't want to make big changes so avoided that but issue is due to an existing bug in aws sdk, https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/21827